# What are the legal aspects around distribution of a new work based on public domain work but in a new medium?

Tags: copyright, trademark, public-domain

For example, [this fan wiki page](http://looneytunes.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Public_domain_films) contains a list of some work that is now in the public domain.

As I understand it, it is legal to sell these works and even new works based on these. What is not so clear for me is what happens when you port over that work to another medium/art form.

It seems, from what I've read that it would be okay to make an extended version of the cartoon or to shoot a live version with actors, i.e. drop the cartoon element.

However, could one legally create and distribute a short video game based on these movies? A potential problem is that while the work has fallen into public domain, the characters are trademarked.

But if so, why is that not an issue if one produces an extended cut of the original?

Otherwise, under which criteria could this be done?

Comment: While probably not a complete answer, this article provides valuable insight into how Mickey Mouse and similar characters manage to evade the public domain for so long: https://priceonomics.com/how-mickey-mouse-evades-the-public-domain/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the public domain, it's in the public domain.  You can do whatever you want with it, so yes, you could definitely make a video game.  I cannot answer the trademark questions.

Comment: This does not answer the question: while the **film** may have gone into public domain, the **character designs** may not have done that. OP wants to know what happens if they take the **character designs** from a film that is in public domain, and uses those designs for an extended film, or a computer game..

Comment: I don't know that.  I said I don't know that.